# How to force oracle accept insufficient swap size?

Tags: oracle-12c, linux

I want to install Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 6.10 with *5.7803GB* swap size.

But one of prerequisites checked failed:

> ```
> INFO: *********************************************
> INFO: Swap Size: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether sufficient total swap space is available on the system.
> INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
> INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED
> INFO: -----------------------------------------------
>
>
> INFO: ERROR: [Result.addErrorDescription:703]  PRVF-7573 : Sufficient swap size is not available on node "olhost" [Required = 7.8167GB (8196368.0KB) ; Found = 5.7803GB (6061052.0KB)]
> INFO: ERROR: [Result.addErrorDescription:714]  PRVF-7573 : Sufficient swap size is not available on node "olhost" [Required = 7.8167GB (8196368.0KB) ; Found = 5.7803GB (6061052.0KB)]
> INFO: ERROR: [Result.addErrorDescription:714]  PRVF-7573 : Sufficient swap size is not available on node "olhost" [Required = 7.8167GB (8196368.0KB) ; Found = 5.7803GB (6061052.0KB)]
> INFO: INFO: [Task.perform:819]
> TaskSwapSize:Swap Size[CHECK_SWAP_SIZE]:TASK_SUMMARY:FAILED:IGNORABLE:VERIFICATION_FAILED:Total time taken [58 Milliseconds]
>           ERRORMSG(olhost): PRVF-7573 : Sufficient swap size is not available on node "olhost" [Required = 7.8167GB (8196368.0KB) ; Found = 5.7803GB (6061052.0KB)]
> ```

How to force oracle to use smaller swap size instead of required?

Comment: Severity:IGNORABLE .. can't you just do that - ignore it ?

Comment: Yes, I can. I've noticed it after question publication, that severity: IGNORABLE. After remediation of critical requirements failure I've run installation without problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly can't, really, unless there is a documented option for that. As the error is marked as "Severity:IGNORABLE" it is not unlikely that there will be an option to ignore "ignorable" warnings and proceed. Check the installation documentation for this information.

If not, and the problem is that you have a fixed swap partition/volume that you cannot increase because there is no space available to grow it into, you could temporarily add more swap by adding a swap file with something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/additionalswap bs=1048576 count=2100
chmod 600 /tmp/additionalswap
mkswap /tmp/additionalswap
swapon /tmp/additionalswap
```

before the installation process. This assumes you have sufficient space in the filesystem `/tmp` is found in, choose another location if not.

Once done, turn the extra swap space off with `swapoff /tmp/additionalswap` and remove the file.

Answer (score 1):

hm .. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/server-configuration-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation.html#GUID-CD4657FB-2DDC-4B30-AAB4-2C927045A86D

For installations on less than 16 GB RAM oracle demands RAM-size in swap space - above 16 GB RAM, swap space 16 GB - on install and most likely also during work (as is stated for restarting)

Going by that, either you reduce your RAM by extracting a RAM-module for the time being, if your server hardware allows that.  Or give it what it wants. I can't imagine that drive space is that tightly limited on the machine given today's hard drive prices.
I forgot the 3rd option - like given in the other answer. To simply create an additional swapfile if space is available.